Server Tomcat v10.1 Server at localhost failed to start
I getting error On Tomcat server like Server Tomcat v10.1 Server at localhost failed to start. but its working initializing after some its getting i have also change port numbers. can anyone help please
Server Tomcat v10.1 Server at localhost failed to start to slove it

Please provide the log (logs folder) or the trace you are getting on the console. Your question does not reasonably contain enough information for anyone to answer it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have clear it in web.xml file on url-pattern I missed the start "/" by this I got the error.final I clear it and thanks for u support guys.
